# Simulate a Long Network Request for Python Testing

Tags: python, testing, server

I need to test a device update function. The function opens a socket on a host and sends a block of text.

The update can take up to 120 seconds. It returns a code for success/failure. To allow continued functioning of the program the update is launched in a thread.

I cannot control the response of the device. The simulation needs to be able to hold an open connection for at least 120 seconds.

It does not need to be safe or scalable since it will only be used for an integration test. The simplest solution is preferred. Pure python is best, but a docker is also acceptable.

Comment: Just write a simple socket server that takes 120 secs to respond to any request. Make sure it listens on the host/port that you are trying to simulate. You can find lots of tutorials for something like this online

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this up based on rdas's pointer.

```
import json
import logging
import socket
import socketserver
import threading
import time

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

class LongRequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        # Echo the back to the client
        data = json.loads(self.request.recv(1024).decode())
        t = 0
        while t < data['delay']:
            time.sleep(1)
            print(".", end='')
            t += 1
            if t % 80 == 0:
                print("\n")
        print("\n")
        self.request.send(b"ok")

class Server():

    def __init__(self, host='localhost', port=0):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.ip = None
        self.server = None

    def run(self):
        address = (self.host, self.port)  # let the kernel assign port if port=0
        self.server = socketserver.TCPServer(address, LongRequestHandler)
        self.ip, self.port = self.server.server_address  # what port was assigned?

        t = threading.Thread(target=self.server.serve_forever)
        t.setDaemon(True)  # don't hang on exit
        t.start()
        return True

    def send_request(self, data: dict ):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((self.ip, self.port))
        message = json.dumps(data).encode()
        s.send(message)
        response = s.recv(1024)
        s.close()
        return response

    def __exit__(self):
        self.server.shutdown()
        self.server.socket.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    # For simple testing and config example...
    server = Server()
    server.run()
    # Send the data
    d = dict(delay=5)  # set delay here to desired
    out = server.send_request(d)
    print('Received: {!r}'.format(out))
```